# Braincrafted bootstrapbundle set input size

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm using braincrafted BootstrapBundle.

How do i get it to render inputs using input-sm?

I have scoured the docs but only seems to be setting for col sizes and not for inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here in Italy we say to do as the ancients did.

For your needs braincrafted has nothing to offer then you just add the class to the input field to achieve your needs

```
{{ form_start(form, {attr:{class: 'input-sm'} }) }}
{{ form_widget(form.username, {attr:{class: 'input-sm', placeholder: 'username'} }) }}
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_widget(form.password, {attr:{class: 'input-sm', placeholder: 'password'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.submit, {attr:{class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'} }) }}
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}


{{ form_widget(form.field, {attr:{class: 'input-sm'} }) }}
```

or in your builder

```
       $builder->add(
            'field',
            'text',
            array(
                'attr'     => array(
                    'class'       => 'input-sm',
                    'placeholder' => 'Fill it',
                ),
                'required' => true
            )
       );
```

Comment: Just a quick question the docs say to extend the form and make changes, is it ok to create a copy of the form class and then add to that rather than extending it?